# Display the Value from a Sorted List after searching the Key C#

Tags: c#, sortedlist

So I need to have a text box display the Value of a Sorted List that matches up with the Key that I search.

```
if (studentList.ContainsKey(Convert.ToDecimal(txtSSN.Text)))
        {
            txtLastName.Text = ******  ; 
        }
```

The *'s are where I am having the issue. I tried string.Join and all it did was show all the values not the one relating to the Key I searched.

Comment: Rather than just seeing if the list contains it, you need to find the one(s) that match so you can tap into other properties like name (based on the very sparse description).  Converting a SSN to decimal seems very odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Value by indexer:

```
var key = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSSN.Text);
if ( studentList.ContainsKey(key) )
{
  txtLastName.Text = studentList[key]/*.ToString()*/;
}
```